# How to handle the authentication for Apps within OneLogin?

Tags: python, office365, onelogin, scim

My company uses Office 365 within OneLogin. Therefore I need to log in to OneLogin first then sign into Office 365 (OneDrive). My question is how do I do the authentication for this in Python? I want to read the excel file stored in OneDrive directly. I tried to retrieve the data directly using python requests module with HTTPBasicAuth and HttpNtlmAuth only to get error 403. I have checked about Python-saml.
https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml
However, I am not sure this is what I need. This seems more like create a server for OneLogin using Python. What is the correct approach for doing this?

Comment: Even though you are using OneLogin for O365, you can also login using your O365 credentials. This way you can use O365 API to access file on OneDrive and while accessing the file provide your O365 credentials. I am sure there must be APIs from O365 to complete this flow.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I have not found out a way to do this using Python packages. There is one workaround though. I used Selenium to simulate log in like a real human and click like how the real human could. It requires some scripting but this way it can bypass the OneLogin security (and other types of complicated security login).